# Mimic a descriptor with a function

Tags: python

I am trying to mimic a descriptor with a decorator function, but have failed. Here's what I have tried.

```
def my_property(self):
    def wrapper(func):        
        return func(self)
    return wrapper

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    @my_property(C()) # this will print 0 for me, but it's not from the obj `c`
    def p(self):
        return self._x    

c = C()
print(c.p)
```

Overriding `__get__` directly in the decorator didn't help me either. I also tried to inherit the `function` class and override its `__get__` method, but was told `function` is final and not subclassable (probably I should try `forbiddenfruit` https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit).

Can anyone help?

Edit: To clarify, I was wondering if it is possible without having to use the keyword `class`?

Comment: Just *define your own descriptor!*. And your decorator should return your custom descriptor if you want to be able to use that syntax. Indeed, your descriptor can function as the decorator, that is exactly how `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, and `property` work, they are all *types* i.e. classes. `@staticmethod def foo(): ...` is just the same as `def foo(): ...` then `foo = staticmethod(foo)`, and `staticmethod` is *just a class*

Comment: Note, in your code above `@my_property(C())` should have raised a `NameError`, you had a previous definition of `class C` around...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for your comment. But to clarify, I was wondering if it is possible without having to use the keyword `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right to override `__get__`. In fact, that's exactly how properties in Python actually work.

Consider

```
class MyProperty:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.func(instance)
```

`MyProperty` is a class whose instances contain a `func`. When we `__get__` an instance of `MyProperty` off a class, it'll call the inner function automatically.

Now we'll make a neat wrapper function for it. Pretty trivial, but still nice to be consistent with Python's nomenclature for functions vs. types

```
def my_property(func):
    return MyProperty(func)
```

Finally, using the decorator.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    @my_property
    def p(self):
        return self._x

c = C()
print(c.p) # Prints 0
```

Comment: important to emphasize, probably, that you could also just use `@MyProperty`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But to clarify, I was wondering if it is possible without having to use the keyword `class`?

Comment: Not in Python 3. Since Python 3, magic methods (such as `__get__`) are discovered on the class, so any attempt to define a local instance variable called `__get__` will have no effect on the instance's behavior as a descriptor. As juanpa pointed out in the question comments, you could use `type` to construct the type directly, but that's still declaring a class (just in a roundabout way), so pragmatically the answer is "no".

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you so much!